# Which icons/buttons to use for help, about, info?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I use the info button to display a settings page.  This page is a modal.  I need another button from here to display "About" info, since I've already used "info" for something.  I have a search form that is accessed only from the modal.  On the search form, I need a help icon.  I can use the info button but that seems confusing, since I already use the info button from the main view to access the modal.  What else can I do for help and about icons/buttons?

Answer (score 1):

An old saying in user interface design: "a word is worth a thousand icons". Just use "About" and "Help", or are you that cramped for space?

Comment: For the search, yes - it's cramped.  I have an info button on the left side of the search bar.  Maybe I can just use the different colored info button.

Also, Apple doesn't use the words "help" and "about", which also prompted my question.

Comment: If you are that cramped for space make sure that you provide some tool tip to explain the icon. If you are a jQuery fan these links might help: http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tooltip/index.html and http://www.codylindley.com/blogstuff/js/jtip/

Comment: What does jQuery have to do with Cocoa-Touch?

Answer (score 0):

A question mark (?) is a pretty safe bet for "Help".

Comment: Yes - I had thought about it but was hoping for something that looked better.  Maybe I'm being to picky.